# Postman: How to specify variables values in body like it is done with path params?

Tags: environment-variables, postman

Postman lets you specify path variables which allow you to input variable value on the go in a small table while consuming a GET route.

[image]

Is there any way to achieve the same for variables specified within the body? So that I don't have to update environment variables every time I am trying to consume a POST/PATCH/PUT route with different data in the body.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could set the (environment) variables in the pre-request script programatically, and then use them in the body:

```
pm.environment.set("variable_key", "variable_value");
```

Please check out [Using variables](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/) for more details.